# Can I change the randomisation seed each run in Rspec with Guard/Spork?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, guard, spork

I'm currently using Rspec for testing, along with Guard and Spork for convenience. I've noticed that unless I quit and restart Guard, the random seed does not change between runs. While this is not a major issue, it would be handy if it did.

Anyone know of a way to change things so that it does use a new seed each time it runs the tests??

Comment: Same issue.  Each run ends with `Randomized with seed 0`, even with the standard random order config in `spec_helper.rb`.  Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: I use Spring instead of Spork (basically the same thing), and RubeOnRails' answer worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

I added the `--order rand:$RANDOM` flag to my Guardfile:

```
guard 'rspec', zeus: true, cli: '--color --order rand:$RANDOM' do
  watch(...)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the following works for me. Add to spec_helper.rb:

```
Spork.each_run do
  RSpec.configuration.seed = srand && srand % 0xFFFF
end
```

[From here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/633).

Comment: This solution worked for me (different "Randomized with seed" each time) whereas @RubeOnRails's did not (always used seed 0). Perhaps my guard invocation is not being run directly by a $RANDOM-generating shell like bash? I use Ruby 2.1.4, Rails 4.0.2, Guard 2.6.1; login shell is $RANDOM-providing bash.

Answer (score 0):

What versions are you using?

I am using guard (1.6.2), rspec (2.13.0).  I am not using spork but it randomizes the seed for me.

Here is the relevant bit that I have in my spec_helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.order = 'random'
end
```

Comment: The issue isn't that it doesn't randomise the order (the configuration is fine), it's that it only generates a new seed if I restart spork.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have random order in spring context but also use the `--seed` parameter add this:

```
config.seed = srand % 0xFFFF unless ARGV.any? { |arg| arg =~ /seed/ }
```

to `spec_helper.rb`.